# Move word to end of string if found at beginning

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings like the following:

```
test = ['ABC 1', 'ABC 2', 'XXX ABC 1', 'XXX ABC 2', 'ABCD 1']
```

If the 'XXX' is present in the string, I want to send it to the end of the string to make it easier to extract relevant information.

Using regular expressions, how can the 'XXX' be sent to the last word of the string?

The desired output is:

```
out = ['ABC 1', 'ABC 2', 'ABC 1 XXX', 'ABC 2 XXX', 'ABCD 1']
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What if a string contains `XXX` more than once?

Comment: Why don't you extract it right away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a list comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
test = ['ABC 1', 'ABC 2', 'XXX ABC 1', 'XXX ABC 2', 'ABCD 1']
ValtoCheck = "XXX"
test = ["{0} {1}".format(i.replace(ValtoCheck, "").strip(), ValtoCheck) if ValtoCheck in i else i for i in test]
print(test)
```

**Output:**

```
['ABC 1', 'ABC 2', 'ABC 1 XXX', 'ABC 2 XXX', 'ABCD 1']
```

- `str.format` to reform the text as per your requirement
- `i.replace(ValtoCheck, "").strip()` to remove the content from the start

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without using regular expression. Like:

```
for i in range(len(test)):
    if 'XXX' in test[i]:
        test[i] = test[i].replace("XXX","").strip()+" XXX" #if XXX present in the list then remote it and then remove white space of both side using strip function and then append XXX at the end of the string.
```

Output:

```
['ABC 1', 'ABC 2', 'ABC 1 XXX', 'ABC 2 XXX', 'ABCD 1']
```